# Get HTML element data in AngularJS script

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, element

I am new to AngularJS and trying to design a page which will have two text fields and two radio buttons.

First text field is for current address, followed by radio buttons(one for Yes and second for No), and last component would be permanent address text field. First, user will enter the value in current address text field, after that if user selects yes radio button then it should copy the data from current address to permanent address text field, if user selects No then it should do nothing. Below is the sample code I have written:

```
*<input type="text" name="cAddress" ng-model="cAddress" required/>
<input type="radio" name="opt" ng-click="copyAddress(true)" />
<input type="radio" name="opt" ng-click="copyAddress(false)" />
<input type="text" name="pAddress" ng-model="pAddress" required/>*
```

Below is the script code inside controller:

```
$scope.copyAddress = function(flag) {
   if(flag) {
      $scope.pAddress = $scope.cAddress;
   }
};
```

when I tried to print `$scope.cAddress` and `$scope.pAddress` values in console then it displayed undefined. Even `$scope` does not have cAddress and pAddress.

Therefore, the main problem is that I am not getting element data inside AngularJS controller

Please find plunker url:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Ub2VEn01HxwDpnCg4tLi?p=preview
Click on Next to navigate to Second tab, there you will find the yes and no radio button to copy the data.

I have minized the code, please look into it. To understand the flow, you can read the README file.
http://plnkr.co/edit/TzJsZIRxAyTuFdCXLFFV?p=preview

Comment: Strange.. Can you show me some more html.. and is the controller properly set in relevant `tag` and this form is under that `tag`..

Comment: You are breaking the golden rule of always using an object in `ng-model`. Objects have inheritance, primitives don't

Comment: Can you creat a jsfiddle?

Comment: @charlietfl I think it's not the issue, but nonetheless its a very good point..

Comment: @Minato it most probably is the issue. If there is a child scope involved it would explain OP's issue

Comment: @charlietfl yup. I guess OP needs to show a bit more of his code to conclude the actual problem..

Comment: Can you show controller code? i think may be $scope not defined...

Comment: I have edited the details and added the plunker url, please suggest.

Comment: Scale your demo down to a minimal representation of the problem

Comment: regCtrl.js : Line 113 regAddressAndContact.html : Line 1 and 34 are relevant to my question
Only in my demo, it is not working... for my other sample projects it is working fine...

Comment: I have minimized the code, please look into it. To understand the flow, you can read the readme file. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/TzJsZIRxAyTuFdCXLFFV?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Try using another scope object.

That is, create a scope object and add property to it for each input like,

```
$scope.myObject = {}; // Empty scope variable
$scope.myObject.cAddress = ""; // initialize your model for the input.
```

And now you should use this variable for your input.

```
<input type="text" name="cAddress" ng-model="myObject.cAddress" required/>
```

Try this. It may help you.

Comment: Bro actually the code given in the question is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Html code:

```
<body ng-controller='Maincontroller'>
  <input type="text" name="cAddress" ng-model="cAddress" />
  <input type="radio" name="opt" ng-click="copyAddress(true)" />
  <input type="radio" name="opt" ng-click="copyAddress(false)" />
  <input type="text" name="pAddress" ng-model="pAddress" />
</body>
```

Controller code:

```
 var app = angular.module('main', []);
app.controller('Maincontroller', ["$scope",
  function($scope) {

    $scope.copyAddress = function(flag) {
      if (flag) {
        $scope.address1 = $scope.address;
      } else {
        $scope.address1 = "";
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Comment: Hi Dark Army, I have tried again and it is working in the sample example which I have created in below plunker :
http://plnkr.co/edit/dq6Qj7UWxNwGVGsnK6Xy?p=preview
However, it is not working for my another practice example, please check in below plunker url:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Ub2VEn01HxwDpnCg4tLi?p=preview

Comment: @RaviNain:If you could tell me which js and html to look for it will save a lot of time and line number

Comment: regCtrl.js : Line 113
regAddressAndContact.html : Line 1 and 34 are relevant to my question

Comment: I have minized the code on this plunk. http://plnkr.co/edit/TzJsZIRxAyTuFdCXLFFV?p=preview